# How can I change the color of my name? 1.17.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I change the color of my name? I've heard people saying something about `/scoreboard teams add` but I'm in 1.17.1 and it doesn't let me.

Comment: I assume you're using Minecraft Java Edition, given the version number? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: `/scoreboard teams` was renamed to `/team` back in 1.13.

Comment: @Joachim that question/answer is for 1.12 specifically, and commands were wildly changed since 1.12 as L. F. said, so that question wouldn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

## for 1.13 through 1.17, you need the `teams` command.

in 1.13, `scoreboard teams` was split into simply `teams`, which is how you manage anything that originally would've been done with the former. unless i'm mistaken, the syntax should be the same.